# when i try to click a button it shows "type error : t is undefind"

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

when  I tried to clic add staff button in my page in firefox it breaks and give a error

> TypeError: t is undefined

But all the functionality works fine..How can i resolve this one.

```
var widget = kendo.widgetInstance($('#staffpane'), kendo.ui);
```

I tried above code but can not find the  solution .Here staffpane is my div id.
[image]

Comment: The line in question can't be causing the error because it's not using the variable `t` which is your error

Comment: i am not using any variable like 't'..in crome its working fine sir.

Comment: and i am trying to debug ..but its shows in kendo.web.min.js file.

Comment: Might be when you execute that line but it is not in that line (alone). I've copied that line to an _empty_ page and it does not complain, so it has something to do with something else. Either start with an empty page and start adding code until it fails or start removing code in your page until it works

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate (but it doesn't have enough information to diagnose the problem); try creating a demo on jsfiddle that reproduces the problem